# Fragment's onCreateView called before onCreateOptionsMenu so i cant expand action view at fragment launch

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, menuitem, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have a refresh menu item in action bar.
I can expand action view (== show progress bar in actionbar) like this:

```
menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.action_view_refresh);
menuItem.expandActionView();
```

I do this when user presses on menu item in action bar.

But now i want to show it automatically when app starts and my fragment shows (in fragment's  onCreateView). 
The problem is that function

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

, where my menuItem is initialized, is called after onCreateView.

How can i initialize menuItem before onCreateOptionsMenu so i can expand actionView in onCreateView ?

Comment: Why not "expand actionView" in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` instead? What is magical about doing this in `onCreateView()`?

Comment: This expanded action view shouldnt be always on, only when i make some http request. But your idea is ok, i handled it this way now. Tnx

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you use `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` to trigger a refresh or some action on menuitems. All the updating work should be put inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. In the case you want fragment to pull the trigger, first you can do something like this in activity level:

```
// YourActivity
boolean trigger = false;

public void invalidate(boolean isTrigger) {
    trigger = isTrigger;
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if(trigger) {
        MenuItem menuitem = menu.findViewById(R.id.menu_id);
        menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.action_view_refresh);
        menuItem.expandActionView();

        // reset trigger
        trigger = false;
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Then, in your fragment createView you can just call the `invalidate` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // trigger the actionview   
    ((YourActivity) getActivity()).invalidate(true);
}
```